# Json to .net translation

Tags: c#, discord

I'm currently working on a discord bot and I want to "translate" this:

```
[
   {
      "command" : "ping",
      "response" : "pong"
   },
   {
      "command" : "hi",
      "response" : "hello"
   }
]
```

to .net code that looks like this

```
    private void RegisterPingCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("ping")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("pong");
            });
    } }
    private void RegisterHiCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("Hi")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("Hello");
            });
    } }
```

Comment: Sounds good.  What have you tried so far and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: the thing is, i haven't tried anything as i'm really new to all this, and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Understandable, but Stack Overflow isn't a teaching service.  What we can do however is help you when get stuck if you are able to ask a concrete question.  Please see how to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: JSON is usually used to serialize/deserialize objects, not do RPC

Comment: @EJoshuaS i disagree.  It is merely a content format.  It doesn't require REST.

Comment: @DavidL Fair enough, that's true, it seems like the OP might be conflating two ideas though

Comment: @EJoshuaS agreed, that is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Json.Net to deserialize your json. Then loop your result.

```
var actions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyAction>>(json);
foreach(var x in actions)
{
    commands.CreateCommand(x.command)
    .Do(async (e) =>
    {
        await e.Channel.SendMessage(x.response);
    });
}
```

---

```
public class MyAction
{
    public string command { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
}
```